# How to Solve Discret Log Computation Problem

Tags: discrete-logarithm, finite-field, complexity

Given $g^a$ in $Z_p$, it is hard to get the solution $a$. Everyone says yes, I wonder why it is hard. Could anyone give a specific mathematical way to show it is indeed hard?

Comment: It's hard not because it's proven so, it's because all known algorithms that can be run on feasible computers (thus precluding quantum computers) are at least super-polynomial in time or space.

Comment: For information, the best known algorithm achieved to solve a [795-bit discrete logarithm](https://caramba.loria.fr/dlp240-rsa240.txt) last december.

Comment: It is depending on the group. Some [have easy solutions some have not](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76241/18298). and also [Summarize the mathematical problem at the heart of breaking a Curve25519 public key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/50405/18298)