# Brute Force on Curve25519

Tags: elliptic-curves, brute-force-attack

I was thinking about a brute force attack on [Curve25519](https://cr.yp.to/ecdh/curve25519-20060209.pdf). For this, we need to solve the discrete Logarithm problem $P = [n]Q \bmod 2^{255} - 19$. $P$ and $Q$ are known Points on the elliptic curve, so we 'only' need to find $n$. The $n$ is in $ \{2^{254} + 8 \cdot \{0,1,2,\ldots,2^{251}-1 \} \}$. So there are $2^{251}$ different possibilities for n. On average the brute force attack needs to test $2^{250}$ different n.

We want to calculate how much time the best supercomputer in the world would need. Bernstein says that it needs 640383 cycles for one multiplication. 92% are floating points operations (flop) so i approximated this to 100% flop. The best supercomputer can do $148600 \cdot 10^{12}$ flops. Combining this information, I achieved the following result:

$$\dfrac{2^{250} \cdot 640838}{148600 \cdot 10^{12}} \cdot \dfrac{1}{60\cdot 60\cdot 24\cdot 365.25} \approx 2.47243\cdot 10^{56} \text{ years}$$

Do I have an error in reasoning?

Comment: You are missing the increase in computing power over time.

Comment: Actually, the discrete log problem isn't $P = n*Q \bmod 2^{255} - 19$ (which is actually rather easy); instead, it's the problem $P = nQ$, where $P, Q$ are elliptic curve points and $nQ$ is point multiplication.

Comment: @poncho You are right, i just did not mention it. I edited it!

Comment: Standard brute DLog force is not parallelizable! The supercomputers achieve their peak with parallel computation. You have to consider one CPU/ASIC etc.

Comment: @kelalaka: you can certainly parallelize a $O(\sqrt{ groupsize } )$ attack (without a ridiculous amount of memory); of course, with Titanlord stating "brute force", he might be deliberately skipping over these forms of generic attacks.

Comment: Might I ask about the purpose of this computation?  Is it to gain some insight into how secure Curve25519 is (and if so, wouldn't it be better to use the best-known attack)?  Or, it is some academic exercise about "brute force"?

Comment: @poncho From OP's writing, I did get only starting from 1 to group-size search. Otherwise, parallelized Pollard-Rho is the beast, right?

Comment: In the case of poncho's question [Summarize the mathematical problem at the heart of breaking a Curve25519 public key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/50405/18298)

Comment: @poncho I'm writing my Bachelor Thesis on Curve25519 (in german). One of my biggest chapters is the security of this curve. I want to write a short subchapter about the pure brute force attack to show its inefficiency. Of course I'm going to write about a lot of other attacks to (e.g. subgroup attack)

Comment: If you're writing a Thesis, you need to use standard terminology, for example, it's not $P = [n]Q \bmod 2^{255}-19$; it's $P = [n]Q$ or $P = nQ$ (both are used).  The $\bmod 2^{255}-19$ is never added, as that would imply we're doing the operation modulo a large integer, and that's not what we're doing.  BTW: what subgroup attacks are there?  We always work in a prime-order subgroup of Curve25519, hence there are no nontrivial subgroups.

Comment: @poncho Thank you for the hint. I just started my security chapter and there's still a lot to learn (especially about correct mathematical description). Bernstein wrote about a small subgroup attack, and why Curve25519 is secure against that. On his [website](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/disc.html) are more attacks for me to write about, and I am going to study current papers to find out about other attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it answer the specific question you asked:

> Bernstein says that it needs 640383 cycles for one multiplication

Actually, when Dan talks about "multiplication", he is referring to a "point multiplication", that is, to the computation of $[n]P$ (given a large integer $n$ and a point $P$).

In your simple-minded brute force search, you don't need to do a full multiplication each time.  Instead, when you have computed $[a]P$ (and decided it is not $Q$), you can step to the next one by computing $[a]P + P = [a+1]P$; this is a point addition (and incrementing the value $a$ you're keeping track of), this is much cheaper than the full point multiplication operation.

Now that is mentioned the obvious misstatement in your analysis, some general advice; to do a reasonably thorough security analysis, you'd need to consider:

- The various computational models that an adversary may have available; in addition to a single large computer, the adversary may have a large number of smaller computers, a set of [GPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit), a set of FPGAs[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array) or even (if his budget allows) some [ASICs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit).  Dan used floating point in his implementation, but that's because modern CPUs have some pretty fast floating point logic, and he took advantage - however, there are a lot of gates tied up in this fast floating point logic; some of the other computational models would use different strategies.
- The various attacks; in addition to the rather naïve brute force search, you would also need to consider various "square root" attacks (such as [Baby Step Giant Step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) and [Pollard Rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms) (and parallelized versions), and also the [MOV](http://www.dima.unige.it/%7Emorafe/MaterialeCTC/p80-menezes.pdf) (which doesn't apply to Curve25519, however you'd need to learn why).

What Dan wrote is a decent starting point; however he assumes that the reader is already familiar with the basics of elliptic curves; I suspect you'd want to do some reading to catch up...

Comment: Wow thank you very much! This is a great answer!

Comment: So you optimized my brute force. But can it be optimized again? Doubling and Addition need a different amount of operations using projective montgomery arithmetic. Is it possible to check every key using Doubling?

Comment: @Titanlord: Hmmmm, good question.  I don't know the answer off the top, but it appears likely; repeated doubling (starting at any non-POI element) will cover every element (other than POI) iff 2 is a primitive root modulo $n$ (the size of the Curve25519 group); that is, if the smallest positive solution to $2^x \equiv 1 \bmod n$ is $x = n-1$.  Verifying if that is true would depend on the factorization of $n-1$ (which I don't have at hand); I can verify that $2$ is not a quadratic residue (and hence the 2 factors of $n-1$ are irrelevant); I don't know about any larger factors.

Comment: @Titanlord: correction to above: the above observation applies to the prime-sized subgroup of Curve25519, where $n$ is the size of that subgroup.  That's the case you care about anyways...

Comment: @poncho: It looks like addition costs ~9M (9 field multiplications) and doubling costs ~6M, at least if you're using projective Edwards coordinates (http://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-edwards-projective.html). Is it possible to do substantially better using the fact that for addition one operand is a multiple of the generator and for doubling the operand is a power of 2 of the generator?