# Curve25519 Attacks and Security

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, attack

[Curve25519](http://cr.yp.to/ecdh/curve25519-20060209.pdf) is a pretty secure way to exchange a key. In the original Paper and on [SafeCurves](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/) a lot of attacks and security aspects are mentioned:

**Attacks:**

- Brute force: This one is theoretically possible but not practical
- Small subgroup attacks: Pohlig Hellman and Lim Lee attacks are useless against Curve25519 mostly because of the chosen parameters.
- Pollard Rho and Kangaroo attacks: Curve25519 is not immune to those attacks, but still provides enough security ( round about $2^{125}$ )
- Batch discrete logarithms: Again Curve25519 is not immune but still provides enough security
- Transfer attacks: Algebraic attack against which Curve25519 is pretty much resistant
- Baby Step Giant Step: Is possible but the cyclic groups are too big.

**Other security aspects:**

- Rigidity: The origin for every Curve25519 parameter is provided
- Montgomery Ladder: Resistance against side channel attack
- Twist: The Twist of Curve25519 is secure, too
- Completeness: addition formula is complete
- Indistinguishability: No difference between a random string and a key

Since Curve25519 was published about 15 years ago my question is: Are there any (newer) attacks and/or security aspects I'm missing?

Comment: [Summarize the mathematical problem at the heart of breaking a Curve25519 public key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/50405/18298)

Comment: I already saw that, but my main questions is: Are there any new attacks since then?

Comment: Here's a side-channel attack using the points of order 4: https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/806

Comment: @Titanlord To be a good question, most of the people here, want to see where you get the results. This can be achieved by providing the links that contributes to your question/knowledge.

Comment: Uhm... My sources where the Curve25519 paper and the SafeCurve Website. Both are linked.